# Printing Administrative title to page

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a function I can use or object I have access to in page.tpl.php in order to get the Administrative title of the current page or it's machine name?

Answer (score 0):

The page title in Drupal doesn't have a machine name. If you want to add one, you can use [Safeword](https://www.drupal.org/project/safeword) module. How to do that: after installing the module, add a new field to that content type where you want to add the machine name; select field type as "Machine name from node title" and widget as "Machine name". After doing this, save the content type and you'll have the machine name for node title.